# jps process unavailable as root user

Tags: java, hadoop

I have successfully installed Hadoop CDH5.2 on CentOS with JDK 1.7.0_80.

Processes start and are running successfully. However when I try to display the list of java processes as root using `jps`, it only returns the IDs and no description:

```
[root@elephant ~]# jps
11478 Jps
2871 -- process information unavailable
2972 -- process information unavailable
3146 -- process information unavailable
3611 -- process information unavailable
2796 -- process information unavailable
3445 -- process information unavailable
```

If I sudo as hdfs, I can see its processes description:

```
[root@elephant ~]# sudo -u hdfs jps
2871 SecondaryNameNode
11495 Jps
2972 DataNode
2796 NameNode
```

What could be causing root not to retrieve the process descriptions?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just visit our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page for more information to use this site.

Answer (score 5):

All these pid's are stored in /tmp directory. Processes started by individual users will be stored in a directory /tmp/hsperfdata_{username}. Seems like root user is unable to read that file. Stop all the processes, Clear the /tmp directory and start all the processes again.After this, try the jps command again.

**Update:**

If you are using openjdk, you will face this issue. For viewing all the hdfs related process, you have to use the command below

```
sudo -u hdfs jps
```

Similarly for yarn processes, you have to use the below command

```
sudo -u yarn jps
```

**If you use oracle jdk, jps command from the root user will list all the processes, provided that JAVA_HOME is defined properly and $JAVA_HOME/bin is in your PATH.**

Comment: Hi Amal, I have tired that but to no avail. It still can't show the process descriptions.

Comment: I experienced the same issue and I figured out the solution and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Amal. Actually I am using the Oracle JDK. I was indeed able to see the processes if I su with the respective users but I am trying to see all processes at once through root.

Comment: You will be able to see the processes from root itself. Can you set JAVA_HOME and add it to the path. Set these commands in /etc/bashrc file.
export JAVA_HOME=<path to jdk home>
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

After this execute the command source /etc/bashrc. I faced the same issue and the reason was jps in open jdk will not show all the process from root

Comment: Can confirm that running `jps` as root fails to show vm data on oracle's `java full version "1.7.0_80-b15"`

Comment: @AmalGJose: what do you mean jps in open jdk? can you elaborate? I used to have no problem but for unknown reason I am receiving this message and I just want to know how to get rid of the unknown process? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run the command as the user that started it. You are probably starting the applications under a different user, which is why you can't view them when you're logged on as root. Try starting the processes as root, so `[root@elephant ~]# jps` should work

Comment: I ran the command as root and I still see this msg: process information unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue after i updated my Java version from 1.7 to 1.8 so i followed the above and tried the following commands and it worked : 
Hope this helps.
`$ sudo su`
then i tried
`$ jps`
thi gave me the the following :
 
`18353 Main
11411 AlertPublisher
20998 NodeManager
20855 ResourceManager
29585
21275 ThriftServer
5302 Main
29637 
18446 Main
22339 Bootstrap
11254 EventCatcherService
21082 JobHistoryServer
25685 Bootstrap
22246 HistoryServer
23637 RunJar
20288 QuorumPeerMain
23561 RunJar
21182 HRegionServer
20372 DataNode
20810 Bootstrap
22201 Main
20511 NameNode
31730 Jps
20440 SecondaryNameNode
21355 HMaster`